# MFC, c++ When showing and hiding ctrls on the screen can I disable paint for a bit

Tags: c++, mfc, onpaint, suspend

I have a screen with say 20 controls on it. 
I want to show all twenty, then hide only the ones that don't relate to what I'm working on.

```
psudoCode.
for each element 
    show element 

for each element in hide list
    hide element.
```

My problem is that between the loops the screen paints. It looks very ugly. 

I know I've seen this done but for the life of me I can't find that code, or even remember what app I'd seen that code in..

Does anyone know how to suspend the paint for a bit?

Comment: What function are you calling to hide the ctrl/window?

Answer (score 2):

As someone suggested to me not long ago, use CWnd::SetRedraw

```
wnd.SetRedraw(FALSE)
... // do your stuff with elements
wnd.SetRedraw(TRUE)
```

Comment: That would have to be called for each control being shown / hidden.

Comment: Are you sure that has to be called for each control?

Comment: If you hide the window it should not take part in the paint process unless something else is invalidating the window or sending it WM_Paint messages.

Comment: I take that back - it appears that, when called on the dialog, SetRedraw(FALSE) will prevent all drawing of children until SetRedraw(TRUE) is called.

Comment: Yes. that is common. In wx this is called freeze/thaw, and it's recursive for children too